Is there an alternative way to Install MySQL that uses a custom config other than using make?
I just downloaded a complete game source code and intend to build a webserver on my CentOS 7. However, there are so many libraries needed, and one of the required steps is to install MySQL in a custom directory using a custom configuration.
Here's a list of the things I need to install:

ncurses-5.9.tar.gz
libedit-20141030-3.1.tar.gz
cmake-2.8.10.2.tar.gz
mysql-5.6.21.tar.gz

For mysql itself, I need to modify sql-common/client.c at line 1911 after extracting mysql-5.6.21.tar.gz, adding the following code:
const char *cli_read_statistics(MYSQL *mysql);
int cli_unbuffered_fetch(MYSQL *mysql, char **row);
int cli_stmt_execute(MYSQL_STMT *stmt);
int cli_read_binary_rows(MYSQL_STMT *stmt);
my_bool cli_read_prepare_result(MYSQL *mysql, MYSQL_STMT *stmt);
MYSQL_FIELD *cli_list_fields(MYSQL *mysql);

after that, I need to compile it using cmake like this:
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/data/local/tool/mysql-5.6.21 \
-DMYSQL_DATADIR=/data/local/tool/mysql-5.6.21/mysql_data \
-DSYSCONFDIR=/data/local/tool/mysql-5.6.21/mysql_etc -DEXTRA_CHARSETS=all \
-DDEFAULT_CHARSET=utf8mb4 \
-DDEFAULT_COLLATION=utf8mb4_unicode_ci \
-DWITH_INNOBASE_STORAGE_ENGINE=1 \
-DWITH_ARCHIVE_STORAGE_ENGINE=1 \
-DWITH_BLACKHOLE_STORAGE_ENGINE=1 \
-DWITH_FEDERATED_STORAGE_ENGINE=1 \
-DWITH_PARTITION_STORAGE_ENGINE=1 \
-DWITH_PERFSCHEMA_STORAGE_ENGINE=1 \
-DMYSQL_UNIX_ADDR=/tmp/mysqld.sock \
-DMYSQL_TCP_PORT=3360 -DWITH_DEBUG=0 \
-DENABLED_LOCAL_INFILE=1 \
-DEDITLINE_INCLUDE_DIR=/data/local/libs/libedit-20141029-3.1/include/editline  \
-DEDITLINE_LIBRARY=/data/local/libs/libedit-20141029-3.1/lib/libedit.so \
-DWITH_EDITLINE=system && make && make install

Everything is fine until I run ./scripts/mysql_install_db --defaults-file=./my.cnf --user=mysql and then I get this error:
nstalling MySQL system tables...2024-04-13 10:26:57 0 [Warning] Using unique option prefix character-set-client instead of character-set-client-handshake is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead. 
2024-04-13 10:26:57 0 [Warning] ./bin/mysqld: ignoring option '--character-set-client-handshake' due to invalid value 'utf8mb4' 
2024-04-13 10:26:57 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details). 
2024-04-13 10:26:57 12733 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages 
2024-04-13 10:26:57 12733 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled 
2024-04-13 10:26:57 12733 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins 
2024-04-13 10:26:57 12733 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used 
2024-04-13 10:26:57 12733 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3 
2024-04-13 10:26:57 12733 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions 
2024-04-13 10:26:57 12733 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M 
2024-04-13 10:26:57 12733 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool 
2024-04-13 10:26:57 12733 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda. 
2024-04-13 10:26:57 12733 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active. 
2024-04-13 10:26:57 12733 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start 
2024-04-13 10:26:57 12733 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.21 started; log sequence number 1600637 
ERROR: 1  Can't create/write to file '/data/local/tool/mysql-5.6.21/mysql_data/mysql/db.MYI' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied) 
2024-04-13 10:26:57 12733 [ERROR] Aborting 
2024-04-13 10:26:57 12733 [Note] Binlog end 
2024-04-13 10:26:57 12733 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting. 
2024-04-13 10:26:57 12733 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown... 
2024-04-13 10:26:58 12733 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1600647 
2024-04-13 10:26:58 12733 [Note] ./bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

Even though the owner of /data/local/tool/mysql-5.6.21/mysql_data is mysql.
So is there any other alternative way to install mysql with config above? Or is it possible to install mysql using yum and modify something to replicate the above configuration?

why would you install a modern software on an old operating system? at least do this in a container, where your installations don't pollute the rest of the system. But honestly, use a more modern operating system, and you'll be able to just use the mysql from the package archives of that operating system. What you're doing here is just screaming for conflicts now and down the line.

@MarcusMüller I still learning linux honestly and I don't know what you mean about modern software. I was thinking all library that I need to install is old. even the documentation I got tell me to use centos 6.5. unfortunately google vm only have centOS 7.0 for early version

CentOS 7 is EOL on November 30th of this year and stopped receiving new features and updates in November of 2019. MySQL 5.7, which is one minor release ahead of what you have, has been EOL since last October which doesn't bode well for 5.6. Instead of using that OS, install either Centos Stream or better yet, Alma Linux or Alma Linux which are binary compatible and more stable which have MySQL 8 in their system repos and you can just run `yum install mysql-server' which is infinitely easier than attempting to build an old, EOL release on an old OS that is approaching the end.

@NasirRiley It doesn't like I want to keep using MySQL 5.6x. it just because I don't really know how MySQL works, especially the documentation I got required specific config.

@flix you're making life harder for yourself than you need it to be. Building software manually and correctly for your system and use case is way harder than adjusting configuration. And, what's the point of using ancient CentOS when you still have to build your ancient MySQL from source? that just makes no sense.

@MarcusMüller please enlighten me, does the config script I've post is just a regular script to install MySQL without modifying something? if so, i would try to install using yum :)

that's not a config script at all, but C source code. And it looks like a patch for an old version with some bug? Really not clear what that would solve, it only introduces function declarations, and since MySQL builds without these, that seems superfluous. It seems especially superfluous to install a MySQL with modified libreadline for a Game Server. This looks super, super sketchy.

@MarcusMüller I see, so I'll try to use yum then. Thank you

That should say Alma Linux or Rocky Linux*
